# Null value posting to MVC action with jQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

**MVC 2**

I'm trying to post to an MVC action using jQuery, but I'm getting an exception stating that `id` is null.  Do I need some sort of attribute on the controller action to accept json packets like this?  Something else I'm missing?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchCategory(int id, string SearchTerm, int PageNumber, int SiteIdFilter)
{
    return Json(AssociationsDao.SearchCategory(id, SearchTerm, PageNumber, SiteIdFilter));
}
```

---

```
post('<%= Url.Action("SearchCategory") %>', 
    JSON.stringify({id: 12, SearchTerm: '', PageNumber: 1, SiteIdFilter: 1}), 
    function(d) { alert(d); });

function post(targetURL, dataInput, success) {
    $.ajax({
        url: targetURL,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: dataInput,
        dataType: "json",
        success: success,
        async: true
    });
}
```

---

From the Chrome developer tools, this is the exception:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SearchCategory(Int32, System.String,
>   Int32, Int32)' in
>   'Current.Web.BackOffice.WebUI.Controllers.SiteProductAssociationsController'.
>   An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

---

**EDIT**

Here's a screenshot of the post data from chrome; I can't see anything wrong with it:

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting the exception? It looks like every other `NullReferenceException`, doesn't it? (btw `async:true` is redundant, it's the default value.)

Comment: Have you tried it without `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: @jrummell - just did; same error :(

Comment: What does firebug (or the chrome equivalent) say is being posted to the controller? What does the post look like?

Comment: Have you tried fiddler to see what is actually getting posted and to where? http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: @Rippo - I guess Fiddler is my next step

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify the `post` function to this:

```
function post(targetURL, dataInput, success) {
    $.ajax({
        url: targetURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: dataInput,
        success: success,
        async: true        
    });
}
```

MVC is smarter than asmx web services.  Instead of insisting on a json string, you can, in fact need to, just pass a plain JavaScript object.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4127389/352552) for more information.

> When you give jQuery's $.ajax() function a data variable in the form
>   of a javascript object, it actually translates it to a series of
>   key/value pairs and sends it to the server in that manner. When you
>   send the stringified json object, it's not in that form and the
>   standard model binder in mvc/mvc2 won't cut it.

---

Also note that the async parameter is superfluous since true is the default value, but that won't hurt anything.

Comment: Did you try removing the extra parameters to $.ajax - see my edit above?

Comment: This is it - mostly - just let me edit your answer to make it complete